# Admob Native Advanced Ads sizes

Tags: android, ios, swift, admob

I am implementing that kind of ads in my app. I want to know which height I can use for that. I found several examples by Admob with ads, but for my app heights in those examples too big. So, I want to know what;s the minimum height and which items I can do not display within the ad

Native Ads Advanced is currently in a closed beta but we have access to use that

Comment: make use of this documentation [Admob](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner)

Answer (score 4):

For Native ads Advanced,please check field Descriptions page where all the field with their type and Required to be displayed? etc. are maintained.

[Native ads advanced field descriptions](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6240809?hl=en&ref_topic=7384666)

Please check screenshot :'[image]

[image]

Comment: So we have to scale the image by ourself?

Comment: set width to match_parent and height to wrap_content as given in their samples.

Comment: What if we want to display it as a banner ad size? Just like the content ad example in this link: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6240809?hl=en&ref_topic=7384666

Comment: @KimiChiu see my answer to make it looks like list

Answer (score 3):

[image: Native ad minimum and maximum width and height]

1. if you want  small native ad your Min width should be 280, Max width 1200 and Min height should be 80, Max height should be 612
2. if you want  Medium native ad your Min width should be 280, Max width 1200 and Min height should be 132, Max height should be 1200
3. if you want  Large native ad your Min width should be 280, Max width 1200 and Min height should be 250, Max height should be 1200
   [visit here for more detail](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native-express)

Comment: NOT EXPRESS, question is about advanced ads

Comment: Hi @dsfs, how exactly did you get access to beta release of advanced native ads in Admob? There isn't much information other than to contact a google account manager.

Answer (score 0):

Use this layout to make adView like list view 
this my xml file

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView style="@style/AppTheme.AdAttribution"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ad_app_icon"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ad_headline"
                    android:text="asjkakjsjkah"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#0000FF"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ad_advertiser"
                        android:text="alkshalkslkajslakjl"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                    <RatingBar
                        android:id="@+id/ad_stars"
                        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:isIndicator="true"
                        android:numStars="5"
                        android:stepSize="0.5" />

                    <Button
                    android:id="@+id/ad_call_to_action"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!--<LinearLayout-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:orientation="vertical">-->

            <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/ad_body"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginRight="20dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"-->
                <!--android:textSize="12sp" />-->

            <!--<ImageView-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/ad_image"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="250dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="175dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />-->

            <!--<com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.MediaView-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/ad_media"-->
                <!--android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="250dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="175dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />-->

            <!--<LinearLayout-->
                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_gravity="end"-->
                <!--android:orientation="horizontal"-->
                <!--android:paddingBottom="10dp"-->
                <!--android:paddingTop="10dp">-->

                <!--<TextView-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/ad_price"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:paddingLeft="5dp"-->
                    <!--android:paddingStart="5dp"-->
                    <!--android:text="100"-->
                    <!--android:paddingRight="5dp"-->
                    <!--android:paddingEnd="5dp"-->
                    <!--android:textSize="12sp" />-->

                <!--<TextView-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/ad_store"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:paddingLeft="5dp"-->
                    <!--android:paddingStart="5dp"-->
                    <!--android:text="100rs"-->
                    <!--android:paddingRight="5dp"-->
                    <!--android:paddingEnd="5dp"-->
                    <!--android:textSize="12sp" />-->

                <!--<Button-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/ad_call_to_action"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:gravity="center"-->
                    <!--android:textSize="12sp" />-->
            <!--</LinearLayout>-->
        <!--</LinearLayout>-->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

get these views in code first set the all views then assign them
this will looks like list Ad